# If $f(X_n,y)\to g(y)$ almost surely for each fixed $y$, $\Pr[f(X_n,Y)\leq\alpha]\to\Pr[g(Y)\leq\alpha]$?

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, strong-convergence

> Suppose that $Y$ is a random variable, $\{X_n\}$ a sequence of random variables, and $f,g$ functions. It's given that for each nonrandom $y$,
>   $$
> f(X_n,y)\overset{\text{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow}g(y).
> $$
>   For a nonrandom $\alpha\in(0,1)$, can we say something about the convergence of $\Pr[f(X_n,Y)\leq \alpha]$ to $\Pr[g(Y)\leq\alpha]$? (It's also given that $g(y)$ is monotonically decreasing.)

---

**Some thoughts**: letting $I$ denote the indicator function and $F_Y(\cdot)$ denote the distribution function of $Y$, we have
\begin{aligned}
\Pr[f(X_n,Y)\leq\alpha]&=E[I(f(X_n,Y)\leq\alpha)]\\
&=E[E(I(f(X_n,Y)\leq\alpha)|Y)]\\
&=E[\Pr(f(X_n,Y)\leq\alpha|Y)]\\
&\color{red}{=\int_y\Pr(f(X_n,y)\leq\alpha)dF_Y(y)}\\
&\color{red}{\to \int_y\Pr(g(y)\leq\alpha)dF_Y(y)}\\
&=\Pr[g(Y)\leq\alpha].
\end{aligned}
I'm a bit shaky on the convergence step and the step just before it. I think the convergence step itself works because convergence almost surely implies convergence in distribution
$$
f(X_n,y)\overset{\text{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow}g(y)\implies\Pr[f(X_n,y)\leq\alpha]\to\Pr[g(y)\leq\alpha].
$$
And then we use the Dominated Convergence Theorem. Is this argument correct? I'm almost certain now that the step before the convergence step is **wrong**. It seems I need $Y$ is independent to each of $\{X_n\}$.

Comment: Yes, the steps in red seem non-rigorous.  Observation: If $Y$ is a random variable that can take only a finite number of values $\{y_1, ..., y_k\}$, you can write $$f(X_n,Y) = \sum_{i=1}^k f(X_n,y_i)1\{Y=y_i\} \rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^k g(y_i)1\{Y=y_i\} = g(Y) \quad (\mbox{with prob 1}) $$ and the desired result follows. So, likely more general cases can be proven by some limiting arguments with some (mild?) additional assumptions on $f$ such as continuity/integrability.